# bridge wlan0 to wlan1 to act as repeater

Tags: pi-2, wifi, bridge

I know, this has been asked many times, but I can't find any satisfying answer 
 given.

This is the idea, the circles around the devices are the wifi range:

[image: pi bridge]

I have a raspberry pi 2 model B with 2 wifi dongles.

How to bridge my router wifi home connection from wlan0 (where the raspberry connects to the router) and brige it to wlan1 (dongle with AP mode available, already checked)? (NO ETHERNET BRIDGE)

I want to use my Pi as a wifi extender.

I see [this guy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36639/hotspot-from-wlan0-to-wlan1-2-wifi-adapters) is saying he managed to do it, but explains it in a very naive way showing no commands and nothing else on how to do it.

I found also these

[Source 1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=112350)

[Source 2 - Good one but for ethernet](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-extender/)

[Source 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=185461)

Can you help me to bundle the things togheter and make this work?

I have come to the point that I have Raspberry making an AP, but there is no connection on it...

Ask anything I will give you info and whatever you need

Comment: `I see this guy is saying he managed to do it, but explains it in a very naive way showing no commands and nothing else on how to do it.`  .... he is not saying that he did it .... he is only explaining why the OP's attempt failed ... i think that you need to look up the meaning of "naive"

Comment: @jsotola My fault! Updated the "this guy" link, check again please

Comment: That "naive" guide is actually pretty good. Did you manage to connect your RPi to the Internet? Did you set up an AP on another interface? Did you try to bridge the two? Unless you're willing to put some effort into it, I suggest you simply buy a WLAN repeater.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The naive guide actually sucks and does not explains how to accomplish the process with the actual commands needed.
I Managed to install raspbian, connect it to the internet and follow the guidelines. Installed dnsmasq and hostapd and managed to set up all the configurations
seen in link "Source 2 - Good one but for ethernet". I managed to get the AP up with a different SSID, but there is no connection, internet is not working and
I don't know how to continue or how to break down the problem further.

Any help instead of useless comments would be appreciated

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The naive guide sucks. Imagine you don't know how to configure a router and You ask here.
I answer: "Yes I managed to do that! Just plug in the router, log in to the main page,
change the password and set your ISP credentials, then plug the ethernet cable in the pc and you're done! Easy wheezy!!!!"

Without telling you that you have to open browser, input the gateway IP, enter default credentials, go to the advanced configuration page,
which fields to search and what to input in those etc etc etc.... Naive guide is good.... sure, good joke

Comment: @LiquidCore The information about what you did (with exact commands) and what errors / unexpected behaviour you have encountered is **exactly what you're expected to write in your question**, not a list of guides you followed. You mention `dnsmasq` which means you're trying to make a gateway rather than a bridge, is that right? Have you enabled IP forwarding? What `iptables` commands are you running?

Comment: @LiquidCore, i looked at the updated link that you posted. ... looks like the OP is setting up a router, not a repeater

Comment: why don't you just buy an off the shelf repeater (wifi extender)? ... they are pretty cheap

Comment: @jsotola wow, ahahha